# About sub thread operation UI

Tags: android, handler

Is the sub thread can operate UI? Or it can only use handler to operate in main thread. But I use this code. It did not launch the error. Is anyone has ideas?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.aaa);
                tv.setText("111");
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot perform UI operation from a different thread. If you want to update the UI, you **must** use [handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Alternatively you can also use [async tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 0):

Generally only the main thread should touch the UI. You are not promised to get an exception otherwise, but you are very likely to.

You should use `handler` / `asyncTask` / `runOnUiThread` as they are the ways to modify UI, other ways may work in some cases, but are not guaranteed.